# Algorithm complexity: How to see "power consumed" as a parameter?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, gpu, metal

Space and time are considered as barometers of analyzing the complexity of an algorithm. But these days with the presence of GPU on mobile devices, there are numerous possible applications which can use that high-performance to run complex algorithms on a mobile device. For eg: iOS's Metal framework can be used for GPGPU operations. But needless to say it consumes a lot of power. So, my question is, if I am developing/implementing, say, a graph search algorithm, on a mobile device, should't I also consider the "power" complexity of my algorithm along with space-time? Now, I know the argument could be that power is something that the algorithm doesn't consume itself directly and I completely agree with that. So, maybe my grammar here is incorrect in saying that power is another dimension of measuring an algorithm's efficiency. But shouldn't power be seen as a performance measure of an algorithm?

Comment: I'm not aware of any formalization of energy consumption, but time and space are probably somewhat useful proxies for energy: fewer CPU cycles need less energy, and fewer memory accesses do as well. For an overview of algorithms designed to minimize the energy consumption of accomplishing certain tasks, see e.g. [here](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2010/5/87271-energy-efficient-algorithms/fulltext), which mentions [this other survey](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~kirk/cs3150spring2010/sigactreview.pdf) in its conclusion.

Comment: Interesting idea.  I think that in a Big-O sense, power consumption can be measured as the integral of memory usage over time, remembering that some nonzero amount of "memory" (at least an instruction pointer register) is required just to keep the CPU running in a do-nothing loop.  For many algorithms, you would just multiply worst-case time and memory requirements, but this framework would appropriately reward algorithms that spend a brief time using lots of memory, but spend most of their time using very little.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I feel, based on your answers, number of memory accesses can be considered proportional to the power consumed. In fact, if this fact is considered as the premise of the argument, then space complexity must me looked at more minutely. This means I can't just consider the net space used but I must also consider how many times that memory was allocated and freed.

Comment: I think the number of memory *accesses* doesn't quite cover it: if 2 algorithms perform the same number of accesses, but one needs n times as many computed values to be simultaneously kept live (i.e. n times as much memory), then it will need around n times as much power.

Comment: Of course on a real-world computer, it won't need n times as much, since the basic operation of the CPU requires a lot of power just to do nothing -- but the total power cost for an algorithm that uses a fixed amount m of memory throughout its lifetime t could (I think) be reasonably estimated as at + bmt, where a is some fixed cost for the CPU and other always-on circuitry, and b is some (small relative to a) coefficient describing the cost of keeping a byte of memory live.

Comment: @j_random_hacker When we take into account stuff like speed/voltage scaling, it becomes trickier still, since energy consumption is a superlinear function of clock speed (in CMOS, something like cubic, but this is a very rough rule of thumb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to be possible, you need a model of energy consumption that you can relate to the atomic operations in your algorithms.

Like "a multiply consumes one unit of energy" and "a memory slot uses two units of energy per unit of time". Maybe the relation Energy = Time x Space could make sense.

Anyway, such a "naïve" model may suffer the same phenomenon as the model of time complexity: it doesn't bear any similarity with the behavior of modern architectures and can be wrong by orders of magnitude.

Using more accurate models would be just intractable analytically.

Comment: Energy = Time x Space is a good first crack.  More refined models *could* be simultaneously tractable and realistic -- look at the success of the I/O complexity model of Aggarwal et al. for modelling systems with 2 distinct levels of memory.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I'd rather believe that refined models are neither tractable nor realistic but this is just an opinion :)

Answer (score 2):

No.
Complexity explains how the algorithm scales in time / memory. Power will be a function of time and memory.

Say you have algorithm A - O(N^2) and B - O(N^3) and they both solve the same problem. For n = 1000 B uses 1 unit of power while A uses 20. Now as you scale it up to n=10k  B will need 1000 units of power while A will need only 2000. At n = 100k B will need 1'000'000 while A will need 200'000. And so on.
This assumes that the energy consumption is constant for the execution of the algorithm.

By the way the same thing happens with time. For example for short arrays nothing beats linear search.

For a specific case (rendering UI on fixed resolution) it makes sense to measure power usage and optimize it. But what works for the resolution today will not necessarily be the right thing tomorrow.

Comment: "This assumes that the energy consumption is constant for the execution of the algorithm." -- probably a reasonable assumption on typical modern CPUs, but there has to be a term in the total power cost that is proportional to the number of bytes of memory being kept live.  E.g. an O(n) algorithm that uses O(1) bytes of memory must use asymptotically less power than an O(n) algorithm that uses O(n) bytes of memory.